# Nested forms with cocoon: permission issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a nested simple_form, and I use the gem cocoon. I have a challenge model, which has this in challenge.rb: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :prizes`
And a challenge `has_many` prizes. When submitting the form, I get the error:

```
Unpermitted params: prizes
```

Even if I authorized it in my strong params. I have used cocoon previously and managed to make it work, I can't find the issue here and I'm pulling my hair off.

In my challenges_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @challenge = Challenge.create(challenge_params)
    @challenge.user = current_user
    authorize @challenge

     if params["challenge"]["prizes_attributes"]
      for k,v in params["challenge"]["prizes_attributes"]
        @prize = Prize.create
        @prize.challenge = @challenge
        @prize.title = v.values[0].values[0]
        @prize.save
      end
    end

    if @challenge.save
      redirect_to challenge_path(@challenge)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

def challenge_params
    params.require(:challenge).permit(:title,
                                      :banner,
                                      :user,
                                      :start_date,
                                      :end_date,
                                      :tagline,
                                      :slug,
                                      :rules,
                                      :category_id,
                                      :organization,
                                      prizes_attributes: [:id, :title])
  end
```

Also, in my form to create a challenge:

```
<%= simple_form_for @challenge do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :title, :label => "Titre" %>
          <%= f.input :banner, :label => "Bannière", as: :attachinary %>
          <%= f.input :tagline, :label => "Tagline" %>
          <%= f.input :organization, :collection => @organizations,:label => "Organization", :include_blank => true%>
          <%= f.input :rules, :label => "Lien vers le règlement" %>
          <%= f.input :start_date, as: :string, input_html: {type: :date}, :label => "Date de début" %>
          <%= f.input :end_date, as: :string, input_html: {type: :date}, :label => "Date de fin" %>
          <%= f.input :category_id, :collection => @ancestors,:label => "Catégorie", :include_blank => true%>
           <%= f.simple_fields_for :prizes do |p| %>
              <%= render 'prize_fields', f: p %>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to_add_association 'Ajouter un prix', f, :prizes %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions text-center">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Soumettre", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

And in my prizes_fields partial:

```
<li>
  <div class='row'>
    <%= f.fields_for :prizes do |p| %>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
      <div class="materiel-wrapper">
        <%= p.text_field :title, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Titre" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</li>
```

Does anybody see where I made a mistake ?

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@challenge = Challenge.create(challenge_params)
```

This will pass the nested prize params into the creation for you, you don't need to manually parse them.

`Create` will attempt to save the record, since you are changing the object and saving it later you may want to use `.new` here instead of create.

Your form is duplicating the `fields_for` call which may be resulting in bad params coming through.

You have `f.simple_fields_for :prizes do |p|` in your view, so you don't need it in the partial. Take it out of the partial and change the partial to use `f.text_field` instead of `p.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However, when I delete the f.simple_fields_for :prizes do |p| in the partial, I have "undefined method text_field for nil"

Comment: @GrahamSlick That's because you are calling `p`, but you passed it through to the partial as `f` (`<%= render 'prize_fields', f: p %>`). Change your partial to be `f.text_field`